# Dax Queries in ssas

Tags: ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

What's wrong in the below code

```
DEFINE
MEASURE DimDate[MyMeasure] = 
    COUNTROWS(DimDate)

EVALUATE DimDate[MyMeasure]
```

I'm getting the following error while running the query:

> Query (1, 1) The expression specified in the query is not a valid table expression

Comment: I'm getting the following error while running the query,
Query (1, 1) The expression specified in the query is not a valid table expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your DAX query must evaluate to a table when you are using DAX as a query language.

E.g. this query is valid because it returns a table with one column and one row:

```
DEFINE MEASURE DimDate[MyMeasure] = COUNTROWS(DimDate)
EVALUATE
ROW("MyColumn", DimDate[MyMeasure])
```

But this query will fail because it returns a scalar value instead of a table:

```
DEFINE MEASURE DimDate[MyMeasure] = COUNTROWS(DimDate)
EVALUATE DimDate[MyMeasure]
```

You can find the syntax documentation from [Microsoft here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492201.aspx).

Please note that this is different from defining measures or calculated columns inside a tabular model. Expressions for measures or calculated columns should always evaluate to a scalar value.

Comment: yuuup dude just like charm,And I can't upvote your answer i don't enough reputation

Comment: Can you tell what function return scalar values and what function will return tables

Comment: Cool. Please mark it as the answer if it solved your issue. Then others can benefit from it too. In Microsofts documentation they should always state what the return type of a function is. When you use DAX as a query language the final result should be a table - kind of like when you use SQL as a query language.

Comment: cool bro,Actually I'm very new to the tabular model and DAX query so any suggestion from your side

Comment: I'll try to add some more details to the answer later, to explain this even better